# Set minimum idle connections in SQL pool

Tags: sql, go

**Background**: I want to reduce the response time when working with SQL databases in my Go applications.

Golang provides an SQL package with a connection pool.
It includes the following configuration options:

- func (db *DB) [SetConnMaxIdleTime](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetConnMaxIdleTime)(d time.Duration)
- func (db *DB) [SetConnMaxLifetime](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetConnMaxLifetime)(d time.Duration)
- func (db *DB) [SetMaxIdleConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxIdleConns)(n int)
- func (db *DB) [SetMaxOpenConns](https://pkg.go.dev/database/sql#DB.SetMaxOpenConns)(n int)

However, there is nothing like `SetMinIdleConns` to ensure that there are always some open connections that can be used when a request comes in.
As a result, my application has good response times under load, but the first request after some idle time always has some delay because it needs to open a new connection to the database.

**Question**: Is there a way to fix this with the Go standard library or is there some alternative connection pooling library for Go with this feature?

**Workarounds and already tried**:

1. I tried setting `ConnMaxIdleTime` and `ConnMaxLifetime` to very high values, but then the SQL server closes them and I get even higher delays or even errors on the first call after a long idle time.
2. Obviously, I could create a background task that periodically uses the database. However, this does not seem like a clean solution.
3. I am considering porting a connection pool library from another language to Go.

Comment: An occasional delay of a couple milliseconds doesn't seem significant enough to warrant the time to implement and maintain a custom connection pool and the resources to maintain unused connections at all times. Are you sure you actually need this?

Comment: A few milliseconds would be fine, but its usually a lot longer (see e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57094912/long-connection-time-with-azure-postgres). And it's not only occasionally. It's happening on a demo system which is maybe used once a week. And in a demo for selling a product, the first impression is especially important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [pgx/pgxpool](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/master/pgxpool/pool.go) library provides a connection pool for Postgres, which allows to configure the minimum number of connections:

```
    connConf, err := pgxpool.ParseConfig(connStr)
    // ... (error handling)
    connConf.MaxConns = 50
    // Set minimum number of connections:
    connConf.MinConns = 10
    pool, err := pgxpool.ConnectConfig(context.TODO(), connConf)
```