# Postgresql minimum connection pool settings using Golang

Tags: database, postgresql, go, connection-pooling

Is it possible to set the Minimum number of connections and the Minimum number of Idle connections in PostgreSQL Using Golang?

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68655261/set-minimum-idle-connections-in-sql-pool